# Is it possible to integrate Spring-Security-SAML-Extension to Wicket1.5 application without spring security?

Tags: spring, wicket, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have two wicket web applications. I want to integrate these two application in SAML based authentication.

Is it possible to integrate Spring SAML extension to Wicket1.5 application without spring security?

Comment: Spring security saml extension relies on spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible. You can use another Security provider like Apache Shiro, or http://www.pac4j.org/, or any other that supports SAML.
You can also roll your own if you know the details too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Shall look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Saml extension dependency

Spring saml extension relies on spring security.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the [pom.xml](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-saml2-core/1.0.2.RELEASE/spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.2.RELEASE.pom) of spring-security-saml2-core

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```